# Why am I getting "Error: Unknown property 'Opportunity_Package__cStandardController.Opp_Package_Rel__c' " from this Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-button, custom-field, related-list

I am currently in the process of making a system for easily adding packages from a list into our Opportunities.

This visualforce page needs to be accessible to use as a list button, but ever since I've added the recordSetVar on the apex:page tag I've been unable to have the lookup for the opportunity resolve on the visualforce page.

the lookup field I'm trying to resolve is {!Opportunity_Package__c.Opp_Package_Rel__c}

When putting this into a apex:inputField I get:

```
Error: Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!Opportunity_Package_c.Opp_Package_Rel__c}'. <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.
```

And when I put it in an apex:inputText to try and just resolve an ID I get:

```
Error: Unknown property 'Opportunity_Package__cStandardController.Opp_Package_Rel__c'
```

**Visualforce page code:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity_Package__c" extensions="MetadataPackageEditor" recordSetVar="Opportunity_Package__c">
  <apex:form >
      <span>Opportunity </span>
      <apex:outputText value="{!Opp_Package_Rel__c}"/>
      <apex:pageBlock title="Select Package(s)">
      <apex:pageMessages />

      <table style="width:100%;">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">Select </th>
                  <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">Package</th>
                  <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">Products</th>
                  <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">PPU Discount</th>
                  <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">Expiration Date</th>
              </tr>

              <apex:repeat value="{!packageMap}" var="oppPackage">
              <tr>
                  <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:inputCheckbox /></td>
                  <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:outputField value="{!packageMap[oppPackage].Name}" /></td>
                  <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:outputField value="{!packageMap[oppPackage].Products__c}"/></td>
                  <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:outputField value="{!packageMap[oppPackage].PPU_Discount__c}" /></td>
                  <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:outputField value="{!packageMap[oppPackage].Expiration_Date__c}"/></td>
              </tr>
              </apex:repeat>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <apex:commandButton value="Add Packages"/>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two standard controllers, one gives you access to a single sObject, the other gives you a list.

When your page only used the attribute `standardController`, you had the single-object controller in your page. This requires you to pass in an ID value if you want to see a record, it queries for you, and you then have access to a single sobject instance by the exact API name of that object.

```
<apex:page standardController="My_Object__c">
```

I can now bind to an instance (you could also say a record) from that object by name, so the following is allowed:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!My_Object__c.name}"/>
```

But if you want the controller that is a list of data, that one is actually called "Standard List Controller" or `StandardSetController`, depending on the docs. The way you make your page use that one is using the `recordSetVar` attribute on your page.

When you do that, you transmogrify the way the controller works, and you no longer have access to a single record any more, and the list will be populated based on the last used List View by that user.

```
<apex:page standardController="My_Object__c" recordSetVar="mylist">

  <apex:outputField value="{!My_Object__c.name}"/> <--this is not allowed

  <apex:dataList value="{!mylist}" var="item"> <-- this is allowed
    <apex:outputField value="{!item.Name} <-- so is this
  </apes:dataList>
```

So it's an either or scenario. Either your page uses `standardController` and you have access to the one record, or it uses `standardController` + `recordSetVar` and you have access to the list of records.

But given you already are using an extension, if you need a list of Opportunity_Package__c records in your page, rather than trying to use recordSetVar like you're doing, I would suggest you just create a new property in your extension and bind to that.

```
public List<Opportunity_Package__c> listOfOppPacks {get;set;}
```

Then you can just populate it yourself when you need to.